# 3d printer not printing circles correctly

Tags: print-quality, marlin, desktop-printer, diy-3d-printer

I am having issue with my new printer it is not printing circles correctly although I have change firmware and stepping of motor
advise if anyone know the solution.
[image]

Comment: Can you give a little more information?  like # of steps per motor, a photo of your printer, etc.

Comment: X axis pulley is 20 teeth with the calculation it's 80 step y axis is 16 teeth pulley so it's 100 step

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible causes for the printer not printing correct dimensions:

- Incorrect number of steps/mm in firmware settings
- Belts are not tight enough
- Pulley slips on the shaft

Looking at the picture, I would go for the first case, because distortion looks regular. Try checking microstep settings on your board, and settings in the firmware.

Comment: yes did it with first case although against the calculation which I did. changing microstepping work out

Answer (score 1):

This could be because your belts are either old or not tight enough. Try adjust or replacing the belts and try again.